# Computer keeps freezing after driver update

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, freeze, amd-radeon

Since a few days my LapTop keeps freezing when I open f.e Skype, Visual Studio or a DirectX based game. When I open one of those programs the screen freezes, but I can still move my mouse. When I try to click somewhere my mouse freezes too and I have to force a shutdown by holding the power-off button.

I tried reinstalling my Graphics driver, but I ended up with tons of different BSOD's like:

- MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
- IRQL_NOT_GREATER_OR_EQUAL
- Something like "Windows had to be shut down to prevent damage"

This is my Laptop:

- Lenovo G570 (Windows 7 / 64 Bit)
- AMD Radeon HD 6300M Series (Driver Version: 14.501.1003.0)
- Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000  (Driver Version: 9.17.10.4229)

I tried installing the drivers from different sources:

- http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool
- http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g570-notebook/downloads/DS010411
- http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows%207%20-%2064

So what can I do? Any help is appreciated. If you need further information, tell me!

Thanks.

NOTE: Everything works fine in secure mode and in normal mode with only the Intel onboard graphics activated.

**Edit**: The "Previous Driver" button isn't clickable! There is also no "yellow warning triangle", so I guess Windows thinks that the drivers work properly!

Comment: back to previous driver? you can do this in device manager->right click the 6300M, select driver page, then roll back driver.

Comment: @Chris.C It doesn't work (see my comment on the first answer)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily downgrade:

1. Go to device manager (search it in start menu or properties of my computer and it should be on your right)
2. Look for the drivers you installed
3. Open them up and click roll back changes or drivers

Comment: The "Previous Driver" button isn't clickable! I might want to add that there is no "yellow warning triangle", so I guess Windows thinks that the drivers work properly!

Comment: I already tried that. In the middle of it my LapTop crashed and it told me that it failed because it couldn't read/write from/to some files

Comment: @Tobi_R Try a system restore  back to when it was working

Comment: I couldn't roll back the drivers, so I just downloaded an older version of the Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 driver and it seems like the issue is fixed. I still don't understand why the newest drivers don't work!

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it. I guess some drivers don't work as well with their new updates